# Using Html and Css in Language Overide

Tags: joomla-2.5, template-override, language, emails

Im trying to overide the language constants that Joomla uses for Registration Mail to add some html code and Css.
As i read from another post here this is possible.
Altough when i add the following code at the override :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<p style='font-weight:bold;color:red;'>Test Test Test </p>
</body>
</html>
```

After i hit save, `<html>` `<head>` and `<body>` tags getting removed, `style='font-weight:bold;color:red;'` is turning into `style="font-weight:bold;color:red;"` and the mail i recieve has the `<p>` tag shown.

Have i to disable some joomla mechanism that strips out the tags or something ?
Or i have to use another approach to achieve my goal ?

Comment: 1. Where did you add the code override?

Comment: I tried first editing the el-GR.com_users.ini file . It didnt work so, after that i created a language overide from administrator

Comment: How about to change < sign with &lt; and > sign with &gt; ?

Comment: &lt; and &gt; getting removed also